# regex of comment out range

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse some code.

For a starter, I need to remove Comment Out range.

I use split function of javascript:

```
var ss = input.split(separator);
```

Comment out is represented as

```
// ....  \n
/* ....  */
```

what is the separator as regex?

Comment: If you want to remove it - why are you using `split`, not `replace`? Btw, it's not that easy to do with regular expressions as you think: `var foo = "//it's not a comment";`

Comment: Well on second thought, You are right. I will use replace for sure. and your suggestion that I noticed already. hmm

Comment: What language are you trying to parse?

Comment: Actually, my own Schme/LISP like Language interpreter running on NodeJS, and I think I will use js/C/Java comment style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zerkms and Anirudh suggested, Strings like

```
var foo = "//it's not a comment";
```

is problematic.

One solution I think of is that

1. Select "Strings" using another regex first.
2. Within the selected "Strings", Replace the characters of the comment symbols to some wacky Strings such as 
   "!@#$wacky1","!@#$wacky2" etc.
3. Replace operation of this Q&A. comment out.
4. Relace back "!@#$wacky" ones to // \n etc.

Done

**EDIT**

thanks to Anirudh:

```
var regex = new RegExp("//.*?(?=[\\n\\r]+|$)|/[](.|\n)?[*]/","g");
```

WORKING CODE

```
Array.prototype.last = function (n)
{
    return this[this.length - 1 - n];
}
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (org, dest)
{
    return this.split(org).join(dest);
}

var read = function (input)
{
    var cmtprts = ['//', '/*', '*/', '(', ')'];
    var cmtprtsE = cmtprts.map(function (s, i)
    {
        return "thisisareplacement" + i;
    });
    //==========================

    var strgs = input.match(/"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"/ig);
    var strgs1 = [];
    var input1 = [];

    // escape cmtprts  during each Strings
    if (strgs)
    {
        strgs.map(function (str, str_i)
        {
            var str1 = [];
            cmtprts.map(function (mark, mark_i)
            {
                if (mark_i == 0)
                {
                    str1[mark_i] = str.replaceAll(mark, cmtprtsE[mark_i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    str1[mark_i] = str1[mark_i - 1].replaceAll(mark, cmtprtsE[mark_i]);
                }
            })

            strgs1[str_i] = str1.last(0);

            if (str_i == 0)
            {
                input1[str_i] = input.replaceAll(strgs[str_i], strgs1[str_i]);
            }
            else
            {
                input1[str_i] = input1[str_i - 1].replaceAll(strgs[str_i], strgs1[str_i]);
            }

        });

    }

    // comment out removing
    var re2 = new RegExp("//.*?(?=[\\n\\r]+|$)|/[*](.|\n)*?[*]/", "g");
    var input2 = input1.last(0).replaceAll(re2, '');

    // "thisisareplacement"+i  back to normal string
    var input3 = [];
    cmtprtsE.map(function (mark, mark_i)
    {
        if (mark_i == 0)
        {
            input3[mark_i] = input2.replaceAll(mark, cmtprts[mark_i]);
        }
        else
        {
            input3[mark_i] = input3[mark_i - 1].replaceAll(mark, cmtprts[mark_i]);
        }
    })
    return input3.last(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `regex` to replace comments

```
var pattern=new RegExp("//.*?(?=[\\n\\r]+|$)|/[*].*?[*]/","g");
```

But remember it wont work if string itself contains those characters

Comment: var regex = new RegExp("//.*?(?=[\\n\\r]+|$)|/[*](.|\n)*?[*]/","g"); //works cooly

Comment: @KenOKABE you are using a diff regex then the one i had answered

Comment: Well, again, your code does not work on  /* */ beyond multilines, so I  modified based on that. Thanks.